# 20 numbers chosen at random

Tags: probability

20 numbers are chosen at random and independently from numbers 1 to 10
What is the probability that 7 is not chosen?

I thought about 2 ways of solving this.

Number 1:
$P(7 not chosen) =1-P(7 chosen) $
Now $P(7 chosen) = \frac{1*\frac{10^{19} }{19}}{\frac{10^{20} }{20}}=\frac{2}{19}$
So $P(7 not chosen) =\frac{17}{19}$
This because we have 20 "places" one is taken by 7 and the other 19 can be filled with any number from 1-10

Number 2:
$P(7 not chosen) =\frac{\frac{9^{20} }{20}}{\frac{10^{20} }{20}}=\frac{9^{20} }{10^{20}}$
This because for the 20 "places" we can choose any number from 1-10 except 7

But I do not if any of them is correct

Answer (score 1):

The probability that $7$ is chosen at any stage is $1/10$. Therefore, the probability that $7$ is not chosen at any stage is $9/10$. You want this to happen for each of the $20$ numbers (note that the choices are independent). So this will be $P(7 \text{ not chosen})^{20}$. Therefore, it is
$$
\left(\dfrac{9}{10}\right)^{20} \approx 0.121577= 12.16\%
$$